Firebase Cloud Functions missing permission on the build service account
To deploy NodeJS (2nd Gen) cloud functions to a Firebase project, I use the firebase deploy —-only functions command. following is the code base.
    import {onDocumentWritten} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
import pkgNM from "nodemailer";
const {nodemailer} = pkgNM;

    // Firebase Cloud Function to send email on new document creation
    export const sendEmailOnNewDocument = onDocumentWritten(
        "subscriptions/{documentId}",
        async (event) => {
          const newData = event.data;
          const recipientEmail = "skysuiteservices@gmail.com";
          const subject = "New Subscription Created";
          const text1 = `A new Subscription was created: ${newData["shopName"]}`;
          const text2 = ` Subscription: ${newData["subscriptionType"]}`;
          // Check if the document was created or updated
          if (newData.after.exists()) {
            try {
            // Create a nodemailer transporter
              const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
              // Configure your email service
                host: "smtp.gmail.com",
                port: 465,
                auth: {
                  user: "skysuiteservices@gmail.com",
                  pass: "vtmi uzgz eiyw eooy",
                },
              });
    
              // Send email
              await transporter.sendMail({
                from: "skysuiteservices@gmail.com",
                to: recipientEmail,
                subject: subject,
                text: text1 + text2,
              });
    
              console.log("Email sent successfully");
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error sending email:", error);
            }
          } else {
          // Document was deleted
            console.log("Document deleted:", newData.before.data());
          }
        },
    );

but when i execute firebase deploy i get the following error.

PS C:\Users\Sameera\skypos-cloud-functions-repo> firebase deploy
--only functions (node:21484) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative
instead. (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning
was created)
=== Deploying to 'skypos360-bedb0'...
i  deploying functions Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR"
run lint

lint
eslint .


functions: Finished running predeploy script. i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment i  functions: ensuring
required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled... i  functions:
ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled... i
artifactregistry: ensuring required API
artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to
determine what to deploy Serving at port 8869

i  extensions: ensuring required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com
is enabled...

extensions: required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com is enabled i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... i
functions: packaged
C:\Users\Sameera\skypos-cloud-functions-repo\functions (69.22 KB) for
uploading i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is
enabled... i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com
is enabled... i  functions: ensuring required API
pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled... i  functions: ensuring required
API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled i  functions: generating the service identity for
pubsub.googleapis.com... i  functions: generating the service identity
for eventarc.googleapis.com...
functions: functions folder uploaded successfully i  functions: creating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function
sendEmailOnNewDocument(us-central1)... Build failed with status:
FAILURE. Could not build the function due to a missing permission on
the build service account. If you didn't revoke that permission
explicitly, this could be caused by a change in the organization
policies. Please refer to the following documentation for more details
and resolution:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#build-service-account
You can also view the logs at
https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-central1/c26410df-de6d-4d37-b068-df028419e2b5?project=365124740735.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
sendEmailOnNewDocument(us-central1) i  functions: cleaning up build files... !  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images.
This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can
attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them
manually at
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/skypos360-bedb0/us/gcf
Error: There was an error deploying functions  them manually at
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/skypos360-bedb0/us/gcf

how and where do I have to grant this access?

Have you followed the troubleshooting documentation it links in the error message yet? What did/did not work as expected? What other things have you tried?

I had a similar issue for an organization that was created recently.  It appears the org level permissions are more restrictive than they used to be.  I had to add the following permissions:
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [project-id] --member="serviceAccount:[project-number]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/logging.logWriter" --condition="None"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [project-id] --member="serviceAccount:[project-number]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder" --condition="None"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [project-id] --member="serviceAccount:[project-number]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/storage.objectViewer" --condition="None"

And then change the created cloud run functions so they could be called publicly by allUsers without authentication.
